# Syntax Error in Access VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

As far as I can tell, this `strSQL` statement is formatted correctly. I've used similar code without any issue in the past. However when I run this, I get a

> Run Time Error 3075 - Syntax error (missing operator in query
>   expression 'BucketID=CA.CAD.BAX.0.3.0.CY AND
>   MaxofMarkAsofDate=#8/20/2014#'.

error message. This is frustratingly vague and I can't figure out what the issue is with my `strSQL` formatting.

```
  strSQL = "SELECT * FROM FXData WHERE BucketID=" & Forms!Correlation.cboCurve2.Value & " AND MaxOfMarkAsofDate=#" & MaxOfMarkAsofDate & "# ORDER BY MaxOfMarkasOfDate "

Debug.Print strSQL

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, Type:=dbOpenDynaset, Options:=dbSeeChanges)
Set rs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("HolderTable")
```

Comment: Include quotes before and after the string value which you compare to `BucketID` so that piece of your SQL statement looks like this:  `BucketID='CA.CAD.BAX.0.3.0.CY'`  Or switch to a parameter query, and you won't need to bother with those quotes or with the `#` date delimiters.

Comment: If your first column (usually hidden) is the ID value then use the following: `forms!correlation.cboCurve2.column(0)`

Answer (score 2):

This specific part of the error message:

> BucketID=CA.CAD.BAX.0.3.0.CY

shows that your BucketID is a **string** and not a number, you should thus surround it with **quotes** :

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM FXData WHERE BucketID='" & Forms!Correlation.cboCurve2.Value & "' AND MaxOfMarkAsofDate=#" & MaxOfMarkAsofDate & "# ORDER BY MaxOfMarkasOfDate "
```

Comment: thanks - I made that change, but now it tells me that :RUN-TIME ERROR '3078': The Microsoft Access database engine cannot find the input table or query 'False'. Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly." I do not call anything by the name of "false" anywhere in this code so I am not sure what this references